# ros2 master and slave

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to setup a ros master machine and a ros master slave using ros2  dashing.

I cannot find anything at all online, only unanswered questions.

So how can I do this ?

Do I need to set env variables like in ROS1 ?:
ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP ?

I understand that with the  DDS things might be very different now, so is there a way to do this ?

Thanks !

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362573/ros2-master-and-slave/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2020-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-30**:
Just to clarify: ROS never had a "master and slave" architecture.

There is only a master in the sense that it knows everything about nodes which have registered themselves as participants in the ROS node graph. Other nodes can then query the master for this information.

But after that, it's not involved at all any more, and communication (of whatever sort) is peer-to-peer (in ROS 1).

Describing a ROS 1 system as "master - slave" is really not something which makes sense.

It would be almost the same as saying your computer or phone are slaves to a DNS server. Which is not the case at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no master in ros2 so you do not have to set it.

But if you run the ROS Bridge there you have to say where to find the ros1 master.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2020-09-30**:
Thanks ! You are right, I kept experimenting and my two coputers on the networks managed to find the nodes by themselves and I didnt have to do anything. Is it because of how the DDS is implemented ?
Thanks !

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-10-01**:
Yes. The dds handles the service discovery.